# What does this error mean?

Tags: python

what does this error mean??

```
Ran 1 test in 0.002s

FAILED (failures=1)
ankit@ubuntu:~/Desktop$ python binary_light.py
Light switched  None
F
======================================================================
FAIL: testOne (__main__.IsOddTests)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "binary_light.py", line 54, in testOne
    self.failUnless(b1.SetTarget(NewTargetValue = 'something'))
AssertionError
```

The Code is:

```
from brisa.core.reactors import install_default_reactor
reactor = install_default_reactor()

import os
import unittest
from brisa.upnp.device import Device, Service

class SwitchPower(Service):
    def __init__(self):
        Service.__init__(self,
                         'SwitchPower',
                         'urn:schemas-upnp-org:service:SwitchPower:1',
                         '',
                         os.getcwd() + '/SwitchPower-scpd.xml')
        self.target = False
        self.status = False

    def SetTarget(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.target = kwargs['NewTargetValue']
        self.status = self.target

        print 'Light switched ', {'1': 'on', '0': 'off'}.get(self.target, None)
        return {}

    def GetTarget(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return {'RetTargetValue': self.target}

    def soap_GetStatus(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return {'ResultStatus': self.status}


class BinaryLight(Device):

    def __init__(self):
        Device.__init__(self,
                'urn:schemas=upnp-org:device:BinaryLight:1',
                'Binary Light Device')



# Here's our "unit tests".

class IsOddTests(unittest.TestCase):

    def testOne(self):
        b1 = SwitchPower()
        self.failUnless(b1.SetTarget(NewTargetValue = 'something'))



if __name__ == '__main__':
         unittest.main()



if __name__ == '__main__':
    device = BinaryLight()
    device += BinaryLight()
    device.start()
    reactor.add_after_stop_func(device.stop)
    reactor.main()
```

Error:

```
ankit@ubuntu:~/Desktop$ python binary_light.py
E
======================================================================
ERROR: testOne (__main__.IsOddTests)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "binary_light.py", line 54, in testOne
    self.failUnless(b1.SetTarget()=={})
  File "binary_light.py", line 25, in SetTarget
    self.target = kwargs['NewTargetValue']
KeyError: 'NewTargetValue'

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 1 test in 0.002s

FAILED (errors=1)
```

Comment: `SetTarget()` should return something that is `True` (`{}` is `False`), which is why the test is failing. If `{}` is expected, then change it to fail unless `SetTarget()=={}`.

Comment: And now you're calling a function without a parameter that it needs. Have you actually read the code and tried to work this out?

Comment: I am sorry....i did not checked it...Sorry about it....Actually I was wondering how come there is no output when I execute the code without unittest?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An `AssertionError` is documented under http://docs.python.org/library/exceptions.html#exceptions.AssertionError:

> Raised when an `assert` statement fails.

Your unittest is asserting that `SetTarget` will return something that is boolean `True`; however, your method is returning `{}`, which is equivalent to boolean `False`, causing the `AssertionError`. To fix this, either test if `SetTarget` has returned `{}` or change it to return something that will be interpreted as True.

If you're wondering why the device code is not working, it's because you're running your unittests before starting the device - and if a unittest fails, your script will stop there.

Comment: ohh....i checked with your solution and found a new error...please see the updated part

Comment: but it should return some output when I execute the file.Thts why, I am running the test case so that it produces some thing. Otherwise , it just exeutes and but produce anything in the form of output.